# How do I append the text tag to just one svg e.g. svg tag with "id=50"?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

**How do I append the text tag to just one svg e.g. svg tag with "id=50"?**

This code appends an svg tag to body with the following properties, and then appends text tag to each svg(`selectAll`). FIDDLE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/dhhw04b8/4/)

```
var arr =[10,20,30,40,50]

//appends an svg tag to body with the following properties 
d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
                 .enter()
                 .append("svg")
                 .attr("width",201)
                 .attr("height",202)
                 .attr("id",function(d){ return d;})


//appends text tag to each svg 
d3.select("body").selectAll("svg").append("text")
         .attr("id",202)
```

This code just appends text to the first svg(`select`), FIDDLE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/dhhw04b8/5/):

```
//appends text to the first svg 
d3.select("body").select("svg").append("text")
            .attr("id",202)
```

**How do I append the text tag to just one svg e.g. svg tag with "id=50"?**

This is my attempt:

```
d3.select("body").select("#50").append("text")
            .attr("id",202)
```

I have also tried `select("svg #50")` but no joy. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is an invalid ID... you can't have an ID that starts with a number.

```
...
.attr("id",function(d){ return "id-"+d;})

...
d3.select("#id-50").append("text").attr("id",202)
```

Comment: thanks for that, here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/dhhw04b8/6/)

Comment: Sure you [can have](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) an id that starts with a number

Comment: @RobertLongson Well, for the`id` attribute the SVG spec refers to the XML 1.0 Recommendation which in turn requires the attribute `id` match the  [*Name* production](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameStartChar). According to that rule the value must not start with a number.

Comment: This is SVG in HTML, not SVG standalone so it is goverened by HTML rules (since it's parsed with a html parser) and not XML rules.

Comment: @RobertLongson - I wasn't referring to the spec "rightness" behind the scenes for this (hence not referencing/googling them).  I was referring to the actuality.  Regardless of the specs, most of the time that you try a numeric only ID, you will hate your life as your css, javascript, libraries etc freak out.  Its one of those specs versus actuality kinda things.

Comment: No disagreement there, numeric ids will bite you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have numeric ids in HTML5, using them as CSS selectors is harder though as they aren't valid identifiers there so [#10 does not work](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters).

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit...

You can work around CSS issues with numeric ids by using an attribute selector, or by encoding the initial digit as unicode as I've done below.

Having seen how painful this is going to be, you might well conclude that **using numeric ids is a bad idea**.

```js
var arr =[10,20,30,40,50]

//appends an svg tag to body with the following properties 
d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
                 .enter()
                 .append("svg")
                 .attr("width",201)
                 .attr("height",202)
                 .attr("id",function(d){ return d;})


d3.select("body").select('[id="20"]').append("text")
            .attr("id",202).attr("y", 50).text("hello")

d3.select("body").select('#\\31 0').append("text")
            .attr("id",203).attr("y", 80).text("again")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body></body>
```